# Error 1904 - Module KinectAudio10.dll failed to register

Tags: c#, wpf, kinect, installshield, kinect-sdk

My application works fine when I run it from Visual Studio 2012. The problem is when I try to install it on PC. I'm constantly receiving the error on the image below at the end of the installation. I checked and KinectAudio10.dll is present on that location. The application runs fine and only crashes on part where I need to play a sound. I'm playing the sound with SoundPlayer.Play(); Any ideas what could be a problem? I'm making installation package with InstallShield. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: The library being present in SysWOW64 has nothing to do with being successfully registered in the Windows registry. Do you have a custom installer? Do you have the KinectSDK installed on the target machine?

Comment: I've made my installer with InstallShield. KinectSDK is installed on the target machine. It's the same machine on which I'm developing my application.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://community.flexerasoftware.com/showthread.php?126412-DLL-register-error), maybe you can build up on this.

Comment: Hey I have the same problem. Did you manage to solve it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Self Registration is not a best practice for reasons that should be obvious to you now.  Relying on out of process code introduces the likeliness that the installation will fail and creates registry values that Windows Installer is unaware of and therefore incapable of rolling back or uninstalling cleanly.

For testing purposes, open an elevated command prompt and CD to your SYSWOW64 directory.  Use the command RegSvr32.exe FILENAME.DLL  to manually register the DLL and then test your code again.

If this solves the problem, reset your test environment back to a clean state and rebuild your installer without using Self Registration.

To this this, find the componentin InstallShield that has that file and look for the Self Reg checkbox.  Disable it.  Then set the COM Extract at Build option to true and rebuild.  Example the build log for evidence of extraction and lack of failure.

Install on the clean VM and test your application.

Comment: Thank you. I'm using InstallShield limited edition and I can't find that Self Reg checkbox. I can only uncheck dependencies to exclude them from build.

Answer (score 0):

Change all references in all project Kinect.dll property **Copy Local** to **false**. It works for me.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same boring problem.
It worked for me just moving the KinectAudio10.dll from the SysWOW64 to another folder.

I guess that InstallShield when it does not find the ddl it just does nothing.
I don't use any kinect's sound in my app so i don't have any side effects.